# How do I pair appropriate xml elements with xmlstarlet?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have two sets of XML nodes, and I want to find elements that have identical "phone" child. For example:

```
<set1>
  <node>
    <phone>111</phone>
    <name>John</name>
  </node>
  <node>
    <phone>444</phone>
    <name>Amy</name>
  </node>
  <node>
    <phone>777</phone>
    <name>Robin</name>
  </node>
</set1>

<set2>
  <node>
    <phone>111</phone>
    <city>Moscow</city>
  </node>
  <node>
    <phone>444</phone>
    <city>Prag</city>
  </node>
  <node>
    <phone>999</phone>
    <city>Rome</city>
  </node>
</set2>
```

Now I want to get the following:

```
<result>
  <node>
    <phone>111</phone>
    <name>John</name>
    <city>Moscow</city>
  </node>
  <node>
    <phone>444</phone>
    <name>Amy</name>
    <city>Prag</city>
  </node>
  <node>
    <phone>777</phone>
    <name>Robin</name>
  </node>
  <node>
    <phone>999</phone>
    <city>Rome</city>
  </node>
</result>
```

I'm a beginner in xslt, and i managed to merge two xml's and put them in a html table. But this pairing is one level over me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a key

```
<xsl:key name="phone" match="node" use="phone"/>
```

then group with [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml) as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <result>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//node[generate-id() = generate-id(key('phone', phone)[1])]"/>
  </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="phone"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('phone', phone)/*[not(self::phone)]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

For readability add

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
```